# Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 3 and 128

Tags: php, mysql, session, post

Currently doing a login and dashboard etc but getting these two errors on login page:
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 3
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 128

My login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'];

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

function Register()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gtaauth");
if(!empty($_POST['Key']) AND !empty($_POST['Username']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.php, is it empty or have some text
{   
    $errors="";
    $query="SELECT `Key` FROM `Keys` WHERE `Key`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['Key'])
    {
        $query="SELECT `Activated` FROM `Keys` WHERE `Key`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       if($row['Activated']){
        $errors= "This key has already been activated. You cannot create an account with this key.";

       }

    }
    else{
        $errors= "Key not found. Please contact us for assistance!";   
    }
    if($errors){
        echo $errors;
    }else{
        //ip insert update
            $query="UPDATE `Keys` SET `IP` = '$IP', `Activated` = '1', `Username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."' WHERE `Key`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if($result){
                $query="UPDATE `Keys` SET `Timestamp` = NOW(), `IP` = '$IP', `DATE` = NOW() WHERE `Keys`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Key'])."'";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }else{
                $errors.="Could not sign up. Please contact us for assistance.";
            }
        //email check 
            $query = "SELECT*FROM `Users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Email'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($results>0){
                $errors.="The email provided is already registered. </br>";
            }
        //username check
            $query = "SELECT*FROM `Users` WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($results>0){
                $errors.= "The username provided is already registered. </nr>";
            }

            if($errors){
              echo $errors;
            }else{
                $query = "INSERT INTO `Users` (`username`,`name`,`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Username'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['Email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                if($result){
                                  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function () { alert("Registration and activation was successful."); } </script>';

                    }else{
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function () { alert("An error occurred. Please contact us for assistance."); } </script>';
                       // echo"Error Please contact me or jelly (skype: mathiis95)";
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

 function SignIn(){

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gtaauth");

        $query = "SELECT `email` FROM `Users` WHERE `username`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if($row['email']){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."' AND `password`= '".md5(md5($row['email']).$_POST['password'])."'";     
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `Keys` WHERE `Username`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username'])."'";     
            $result1=mysqli_query($con,$query1);
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

            if($row){    
                if(!empty($row['password']) AND !empty($row['username']))
                {
                     $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                     $_SESSION['isstaff']=$row['isStaff'];
                     $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
                     $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
                     $_SESSION['key']=$row1['Key'];
                     $_SESSION['date']=$row1['DATE'];
                     $_SESSION['ip']=$row1['IP'];
                     header("Location: dashboard.php");
                }else{
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function () { alert("Incorrect email or password."); } </script>';
                    //echo "Incorrect Email Or Password";
              }
           }
        }
    }

if(isset($_POST['licence']))
{
    Register();
}

if(isset($_POST['sign']))
{
   SignIn();
}

if($_SESSION['id']){
    $isLogin = 1;
}else{
    $isLogin=0;
}
?>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="We are a development team based around the Playstation 3, providing you with a range of things from SPRX menus to a future RTM tools!">
    <meta name="author"      content="Independence Staff">

    <title>Independence | Login & Register</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/gt_favicon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,600|Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for our template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="page-signin">

    <section class="section section-signin">

        <p class="text-center"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Independence Sprx"></a></p>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body" role="tabpanel">

                <!-- forms container -->
                <div class="tab-content">

                    <!-- login -->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="do-login">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <br>
                            Please use the form below to login to your account.
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-action" name="sign" type="submit">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of login -->

                    <!-- register -->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="do-register">
                        <h3 class="text-center">License Registration</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <br>
                            Register and Activate your License Key.
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="key" type="text" class="form-control" name="Key" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" />
                                <script>jQuery(function($){$("#key").mask("****-****-****",{placeholder:"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"});});</script>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-action" name="licence" type="submit">Register License</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of register -->

                    <!-- forgot password -->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="do-forgotpass">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Reset password</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <br>
                            A confirmation link will be sent to your email.
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-action" type="submit">Reset password</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of forgot password -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of forms container -->

                <!-- the switch between forms -->
                <ul class="toggler text-center small list-unstyled" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active">Changed your mind? <a href="#do-login" aria-controls="do-login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Back to login form</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation">Have a license key? <a href="#do-register" aria-controls="do-register" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Activate it now</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#do-forgotpass" aria-controls="do-forgotpass" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Forgot password?</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /panel -->

    </section>

    <!-- Faster loading -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['id'];
```

not describe and you should check for example `isset($_SESSION['id'])` and than flow.

Comment: Thank you. I just has to change `$_SESSION['id'];` to `isset($_SESSION['id'])`

Answer (score 0):

You have a started the session , so you will get the session id for sure 
try

```
session_id() instead of $_SESSION['id'];
```